# Adsense Anchor ads and Side rail ads not displaying on Chrome Desktop

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, desktop, adsense, adsense-anchor-ads

I added into the head of the page the script for automatically displaying Adsense banners.
Anchor ads and Side rail ads are displayed fine in Firefox desktop but not displaying in Chrome desktop.
I have not installed any Ads blocker plugins in Chrome and I also tested with anonymous windows.
Also Adsense Ads help page did not helped me.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
The url of the site is https://www.tarocchidea.com

Thank you

I also tried to put the script before the closing  tag with no avail

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The AdSense ecosystem decides whether to show Anchor ads and Side rail ads. I see ads. Everything is OK.